# Command not working in an interpreter I made

Tags: python, command, interpreter

(Please bear with me, my code is really sloppy and it might be a little hard to understand, mainly because of all the variables, `global`s and if statements...)

I've created an interpreted, esoteric, tape-based programming languaged designed for code golf named Tellurium (it's an element fyi). So far, it's been working pretty good except for the conditional statements.

Here's the syntax of a conditional statement:

`(integer[code]`

Here's the Python equivalent of it:

`if tape[selectedCell] == integer:
      code`

So, my problem is that you can only use the statements once in a code. Use it more that one time, and it doesn't work. It doesn't even throw an error. It does nothing.

---

Here's some examples of commands that don't work, and what they should output.

`(0[^](1[^]+(1[^]`  Should output 0 followed by 1. Instead, outputs **only** 0. I think it has something to do with the **first** `(1[^]`, which should be skipped by the interpreter, since the selected cell's value isn't 1.

Here's another example: `+++++(0[^](5[^]`. The cell's value is incremented to 5. Then, `(0[^]`checks if the cell's value is equal to zero. Well, it isn't, so it should be skipped. Next, `(5[^]` checks if the cell's value is equal to five. It is, and it *should* output `5`. Instead, it outputs `5\n5`.

Yet another example: `(0[^](1[^](0[^]`. The `(1[^]` instruction should be completely ignored by the interpreter, because the cell's value isn't 1. It's still zero. So, the desired output should be `0\n0`, since there are two `0[^]` commands.

`(0[^]` works perfectly. It outputs the cell's value, which is 0.

**I think that the problem has something to do with statements that should be skipped, like the `(1[^]`in example 2.**

---

I don't know why this doesn't work, I've tried I know. I'd appreciate some help, I'd really like to get this language up and going again!

---

So, here's the interpreter without all of the extra commands.

```
tape = [0] * 25500
readingNum = False
readingIf = False
num = []
code = []
selectedCell = 0

def prompt():
    userInput = input("> ")
    return userInput

def read(cmd):
    length = len(cmd)
    commands = list(cmd)
    for i in range(0, length):
        parse(commands[i])

def parse(cmd):
    global tape
    global readingNum
    global readingIf
    global num
    global code
    global selectedCell

    if readingNum == True:
        if cmd == "[":
            readingNum = False
            readingIf = True

        else:               
            num.append(cmd)

    elif readingIf == True:
        if cmd == "]":
            readingIf = False
            if tape[selectedCell] == int(''.join(num)):
                read(code)
                code = []
                num = []

            else:
                return

        else:
            code.append(cmd)

    elif cmd == "^":
        print(tape[selectedCell])

    elif cmd == "+":
        tape[selectedCell] += 1

    elif cmd == "(":
        readingNum = True

    else:
        print("Error")

while 1:
    read(prompt())
```

Comment: This really needs to be a [mcve]. We're not going to read the code for your entire interpreter to debug it for you. You need to spend more time narrowing down the issue.

Comment: Best advice -- add judicious amounts of print statements OR get comfortable with the python debugger and step through the code line by line.

Comment: @MorganThrapp I updated the post with a version of the interpreter without all of the extra commands. (Much shorter)

Comment: That's a lot better. Can you add a specific set of instructions that don't work and what they should produce? And specifically a set that is compatible with the smaller version you posted.

Comment: `if tape[selectedCell] == int(''.join(num))` You're never putting anything on the tape. Also, you REALLY, REALLY, REALLY need to move away from all those global variables. It's going to make it incredibly hard to debug.

Comment: @MorganThrapp Nothing needs to be put in the tape in that if statement, because all it's doing is comparing the currently selected cell's value to `''.join(num)` Also, I added some examples. They might be a bit hard to understand, since it's an esoteric programming language. Also, I'm a bad explainer.

Comment: Right, but there's no value in any of the cells, so that will only be true if `num` is 0.

Comment: @MorganThrapp I don't know how I should move away from the globals. If I remove them, the program won't run.

Comment: @MorganThrapp Aha, I'll try fixing it and seeing if it works. EDIT: single conditional statements are working fine, but there seems to be something wrong with multiple ones on a single line.

Comment: @MorganThrapp Oh, I found out why it outputs "Error". The spaces aren't commands, and every character that isn't a valid command throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't working because you're using globals. When you hit `if tape[selectedCell] == int(''.join(num)):` for the third if statement, `nums` contains `['1', '1']` because both if statements have added a 1 to `num`, so when you do `int(''.join(num))` you end up with `11` which is not equal to `1`.

You need to refactor this code to stop using globals. For a working example of how to not use globals to represent a stack, take a look at the [esolang I wrote a couple months back](https://github.com/morganthrapp/Pylons-lang). It's not as finished as I'd like, but it has a working stack without globals.

Comment: Yes, but if I add one to the cell using `+`, then the second `(1[^]` should output 1, because the cell's value is one. (`+` increments the value)

Comment: @m654 I updated my answer. It all comes down to the issue I mentioned before about needing to get away from globals. This isn't going to work until you get away from them.

Comment: @MorhanTharpp Should I declare all of the variables _inside_ of the parse() function? I'm pretty sure I won't need globals if I do that.

Comment: Nope, because then you'll lose them when you recurse to parse if statements. Take a look at the code I linked in my post for a better idea. It's not easy, but it's doable.

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://paste.ee/p/PvlQf)? It doesn't have any globals.

Comment: @m654 That certainly looks a bit better. I'm not sure how much more I'll be able to walk you through this, but that looks like a better start.

Comment: To be honest I don't know what else to do. Conditionals still don't seem to work. I guess I'll remove them for now, maybe implement them later